# docker-compose fails at adding veth (virtual interface) to bridge docker0

Tags: linux, networking, docker, docker-compose

**Issue**:
Here's my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
    elasticsearch:
        image: 'elasticsearch:latest'
        ports:
            - "9200:9200"

    logstash:
        build: './logstash_image'
        links:
            - elasticsearch
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
            - "5001:5001"
            - "5201:5201"
            - "5202:5202"
            - "5203:5203"

    kibana:
        image: 'kibana:latest'
        ports:
             - '5601:5601'
        links:
             - elasticsearch
        volumes:
             - ./kibana.yml:/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml
```

And here's my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM logstash:latest

LABEL maintainer1.name="anon" \
      maintainer1.email="anon@mail.com" \
      maintainer2.name="myname" \
      maintainer2.email="myname@somemail.com"

RUN /opt/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-log4j2-logstash2 logstash-output-syslog
# FIX: use `logstash-input-log4j2` instead of `logstash-input-log4j2-logstash2`?
# other plugins: logstash-input-http, logstash-input-log4j
COPY logstash.conf /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["logstash","-f","/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf", "--debug"]
```

This used to build just fine a few days ago, however currently I'm getting the following error message:

```
[root@somemachine elk_stack]# docker-compose up -d
Creating network "elkstack_default" with the default driver
Building logstash
Step 1 : FROM logstash:latest
 ---> 1ca34df702f8
Step 2 : LABEL maintainer1.name ...
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6dd78ac216f2
Step 3 : RUN /opt/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-log4j2-logstash2 logstash-output-syslog
 ---> Running in 885b0429b3a4
ERROR: Service 'logstash' failed to build: failed to create endpoint focused_almeida on network bridge: adding interface veth0491201 to bridge docker0 failed: operation not supported
```

**ERROR: Service 'logstash' failed to build: failed to create endpoint focused_almeida on network bridge: adding interface veth0491201 to bridge docker0 failed: operation not supported**

So it seems like (1) docker-compose is assigning a randomly generated name to the logstash service instead of `elkstack_logstash_1` presumably because the compose did not fully go through.
(2) `veth0491201` is unable to attach to the bridge `docker0` for some reason, because of this I can't reach the internet from within the container as it's not connected through `docker0`.

**Investigation**:
`docker ps -a` after the compose:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
885b0429b3a4        6dd78ac216f2                "/bin/sh -c '/opt/log"   18 minutes ago      Created                                                          focused_almeida
```

`docker network ls` after the compose:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                          DRIVER            
23bcc8c01ad4        bridge                        bridge              
4aea66903c6b        none                          null                
67cb26c508d9        host                          host                
9fc4a42bbcf6        elkstack_default              bridge
```

`docker network inspect elkstack_default`:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "elkstack_default",
        "Id": "9fc4a42bbcf6800889f8e9bc71ab394ebf6f97b21e0ce2345253b055d17138aa",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {}
    }
]
```

`route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.120.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 docker0
10.0.120.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 docker0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-83e64c848669
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-9fc4a42bbcf6
```

**Troubleshooting leads**:

1. `docker --version`: Docker version 1.10.2, build c3959b1
   `docker-compose --version`: docker-compose version 1.8.0, build f3628c7
   Some networking bug in Docker?
2. The machine at which I'm doing this has recently done some config changes in regards to its network, firewalls etc.
   **I think it's using `172.18.0.0` for something else, so when Docker tries to use that route it gets blocked.**
   How can I troubleshoot or determine if it's an issue with the machines network settings?
3. Following up on point made in (2), I tried to make a docker-compose where the network is explicitly defined, this didn't seem to work either:

> ```
> networks:
>     net:
>         driver: bridge
>         ipam:
>             driver: default
>             config:
>             - subnet: 172.30.0.0/16
>               ip_range: 172.30.5.0/24
> ```

- I'm able to docker-compose another stack of services on the machine, this leads me to believe that it's a Docker-related or docker-compose-related flaw, either in the application itself or my configuration.
- I'm able to get this to work on my local machine, this leads me to believe that it's an issue with the remote machine where I'm having issues.

  uname -a: `Linux somemachine 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 16 17:03:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
  cat /etc/centos-release: `CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)`

**Related info & issues:**
 - http://54.71.194.30:4017/articles/networking/#how-docker-networks-a-container
 - https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23047
 - https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15341

Comment: Seems to have been an issue with network interfaces on the machine. The `docker0` bridge was set as the default network interface instead of `eth0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with the network interface on the machine.
eth0 was not set as the default, instead **docker0 was the default interface** causing errors.

Read more here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html
To fix this issue, changes were made to the files contained in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` which specify how the network interfaces are configured.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem looks to be related with your system configuration.

Please, could you try to add manually, with unix command brctl the veth into the bridge ?

The command should be:

brctl addif veth0491201 docker0

This is the command done by the script to start your VM that is failling.
By troubleshooting that step may explain the reason.

I suspect the type of veth is not compatible on YOUR system, and you have to know why. May be a bug into your system regarding the bridge software part.

For sûre, your problem is not linked with your ip setting.

You may try to upgrade OR downgrade your kernel, by testing different kernel releases.

Without more details about what exactly happens during the command
"brctl addif veth0491201 docker0" I cannot say more things.

That will return the same "Operation not supported" error message, but by checking everything about both interfaces, you may find either, a good reason why the "operation is not supported" (wrong type interface) or a kernel bug with (good type of interface).

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment under my question, it was an issue with the network interface on the machine.  
eth0 was not set as the default, instead docker0 was the default interface causing errors. Read more here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html  

To fix this issue, changes were made to the files contained in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` which specify how the network interfaces are configured.